# Algebraic form of complex number

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to obtain the result of a definite integral as a complex number expressed in the algebraic form. I tried:

```
Integrate[E^z, {z, 0, 1 + I \[Pi]/4}] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &
```

but the result is not what I expected. How can I obtain `-1+E/Sqrt[2]+I E/Sqrt[2]`? Moreover, is it possible to rationalize the denominator of the fractions?

Comment: `ExpToTrig` work.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `Plus` needs to be inactive:

```
x = Integrate[E^z, {z, 0, 1 + I π/4}] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &;
Inner[Times, ReIm[x], {1, I}, Inactive[Plus]]
(* (-1+E/Sqrt[2])+(I E)/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
ee = -1 + ((1 + I) E)/Sqrt[2] /. 
      Complex[aa_, bb_] -> aa + HoldForm[I]*bb // Expand

(*   -1+E/Sqrt[2]+(E I)/Sqrt[2]   *)

ee // ReleaseHold
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful.